# Can I recover an overwritten incident trace file?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, recovery

I was looking at incident trace file in oracle database but some how that file got overwritten. As of now I have ecrep_ora_26467_i49966.trm but trhe corresponding .trc file is lost. is it possible to recreate the lost trace file

Answer (score 1):

No, not within Oracle.  This can only be recovered if you backed it up externally.

Comment: Sure . Thanks luckily I created ips package before i got trace files deleted.